# Setting up web-service for interaction with QuickBooks through the web-connector

Tags: quickbooks

I'm trying to create web-service, which will be able to interact with QuickBooks through the web-connector.

The problem is that when I try to add qwc file into web-connector, it fails to add an application with next error: Parameter length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length. The new application was not added.

Here is my qwc file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
<AppName>x2</AppName>
<AppID></AppID>
<AppURL>https://...</AppURL>
<AppDescription></AppDescription>
<AppSupport>https://.../support</AppSupport>
<UserName>Max</UserName>
<OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
<FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
<QBType>QBFS</QBType>
<Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>60</RunEveryNMinutes>
</Scheduler>
<IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

I don't see anything helpful in the logs too.
Also I'm not sure what my web-service supposed to do whenever web-connector tries to add an application for the first time.

Any help is very appreciated.

**UPDATED:** OMG, I've made my endpoint explicit (appended /app.php to the app url) and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are not using a valid URL.

Does your URL just point to a domain name perhaps? Is it not pointing to an actual file?

e.g.

`http://www.your-domain.com`

vs.

`http://www.your-domain.com/some/script.php`

Also, since you're using PHP, make sure to check out [the open-source PHP DevKit for QuickBooks](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) - it migth save you some time and effort (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Yeah, that was the cause. And I'm already using it, thank you for it.